# Вывод файла в echo

Tags: php, echo

Здравствуйте, вывожу кусок кода переменной echo, но include файла не работает, помогите как можно решить данную проблему ?Вот кусок кода

```
     if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
        == 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $str = <<<EOF
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="registerHere" method='post' action=''>
          <fieldset style="border: 0px;">                       
         <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls" >
      <a href="$you_id">$youname</a>
          </div>
              </div>
    include("load_tweets.php");
    EOF;
echo $str
```

Почему файл не выводиться при помощи include ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставьте include после EOF, в режиме inline file или как он там называется (<<<), операторы не работают, потому-что этот режим специально предназначен для того чтобы в нем не работали операторы.

Но вообще вам видимо хочется вывод этого файла в переменную положить, я хотел об этом способе написать в вашем предыдущем вопросе, но как-то не посчитал нужным, этот способ называется [Включение буферизации вывода](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php)

```
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    == 'xmlhttprequest') {
ob_start(); //теперь весь вывод пойдет в буфер
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="registerHere" method='post' action=''>
      <fieldset style="border: 0px;">                       
     <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls" >
            <a href="<php echo $you_id; ?>"><?php echo $youname; ?></a>
          </div>
     </div>
<?php
include("load_tweets.php");
$str=ob_get_clean(); //копируем буфер в переменную,очищаем буфер, вывод опять в stdout

echo $str
```

Comment: получается данный php файл всунуть нереально в EOF что бы он сработал ?

Comment: @LovelyCat, достаточно прочитать всего одну строку в мануалах:

> Heredoc-текст ведет себя так же, как и
> строка в двойных кавычках...

О каких "всунуть файл" может идти речь?